# Regex for matching 3 or 4 or 5 letter words starting with "ho", but not included hou in hour

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match words starting with "ho" in a text. Matching words length should be maximum 5 and it should exclude `hou` in `hour`.

I currently struggle in adding length limits and excluding `hou` in `hour`.

My code is here:

```
demotext="what I have to do is to love you forever. however, we only have one hour left to be together. whatttttttttt. hot. hottest."

m = re.findall(r'\bwh\w+|\bho\w+',demotext)

print(m)
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?:wh|ho(?!ur\b))[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\b
```

If the `hours` should also be excluded, add `s?` after `r`,

```
\b(?:wh|ho(?!urs?\b))[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DjBStj/4).

**Regex details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:wh|ho(?!urs?\b))` - Group 1: either `wh`, or `ho` not followed with `ur` and an optional `s` and a word boundary
- `[a-zA-Z]{1,3}` - one, two or three letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.

**Python demo**

```py
import re
text = r"what I have to do is to love you forever. however, we only have one hour left to be together. whatttttttttt. hot. hottest."
print(re.findall(r'\b(?:wh|ho(?!ur\b))[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\b', text))
# => ['what', 'hot']
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Actually my code needs to match words starts with wh and ho. Your code provided here works. However, I need to add length limits to wh as well. I tried \b(wh[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\w+|ho(?!ur\b)[a-zA-Z]{1,3})\b. It didn't work though.

Comment: I got it. Thank u for the regex details.

Comment: @Seanisgod I added a Python demo.

Answer (score 0):

Funny one. This should do the trick `\b(?!hour\b|hou\b)(ho[a-zA-Z]{1,3})\b`.